# Interactive Graph in R, straight line changing parameters

Tags: r, graph, slider

I'm wondering if in RStudio there's a way to plot an interactive graph with a slider. I want to plot a straight line and I want to create a slider that changes the intercept and the slope.
For example like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wubxhfcyie) where a and b are my sliders which I'm free to move as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
library(manipulate)
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.1)

manipulate(plot(x,slope*x+intercept), slope = slider(0, 100), 
           intercept = slider(-100,100))
```

Here's a screen shot of the plot output:
[image]

Another option is to make a shiny app:

```
#save this script as app.R
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Linear Equation App"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput(inputId = "slope",label = "Slope:",
                     min = 0,max = 100,value = 0),
         sliderInput(inputId = "intercept",label = "Intercept",
                     min = -100,max = 100,value = 0)
      ),


      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("lineplot")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

   output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
      x <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.1)
      y <- x*input$slope + input$intercept
      plot(x,y)
      })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Screenshot of the shiny app.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example with shiny + ggplot2. Easy enough to create a line where x1 = 1, x2 = 2, and y are calculated based on inputs from the sliders using y1 = mx1+b; y2 = mx2+b.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
 strong("This is an interactive line"),
 sliderInput("slope", "Define slope:", min = -100, max = 100, value = 0, step = 0.01),
 sliderInput("intercept", "Define intercept:", min = -10000, max = 10000, value = 0, step = 1),
 plotOutput("linePlot"))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$linePlot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = c(1, 2),
                       y = c(input$slope*1+input$intercept, input$slope*2+input$intercept))) +
    geom_line()
})
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```